# Countdown to 1st of each month Javascript (refresh each month)

Tags: javascript, countdown

I'm trying to implement a countdown script which countdowns to the first day of the next calendar month.
So far, I can only find scripts which countdown to an absolute date.

I looked through every scripts of [this site](http://www.hotscripts.com/category/scripts/javascript/scripts-programs/countdowns/) and none meet the requirements.

Does anybody know of any script that does this? I am using a regular countdown at this moment but I have to edit the new date on the 1st of every month. I'd like to have an automatically adjusting one instead.

Comment: Since you are already "using a regular countdown at this moment", why don't you edit your question to include the "regular countdown" and where you've tried to modify it so that it knows when a month has rolled over? This will make your question much easier to answer (and a better fit for SO).

Answer (score 0):

```
function tilTheFirst(){
 var D=new Date(), f=new Date(D);
 f.setMonth(f.getMonth()+1,1);
 f.setHours(0,0,0,0);
 return f-D;
}
```

1. create a new Date for the current moment.
2. create a new Date for the first moment of the first of the next month.
3. return the difference